# How to use self(php) like keyword in java?

Tags: java, php

I wonder that java has no any keyword like **self** in php to get the same result as this php code yields.

```
    <?php
   class Person {
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->getName()." the programmer";
    }

    public function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello, I'm ".$this->getTitle()."<br/>";
    }

    public function sayGoodbye() {
        echo "Goodbye from ".self::getTitle()."<br/>";  
    }
}

class Geek extends Person {
    public function __construct($name) {
        parent::__construct($name);  //calling person class's constructor
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->getName()." the geek";
    }
}

$geekObj = new Geek("Avnish alok");
$geekObj->sayHello();
$geekObj->sayGoodbye();

/*This will output:

    Hello, I'm Avnish alok the geek
    Goodbye from Avnish alok the programmer
    */


?>
```

In java, i wrote the same code but the result was differ. Look at my java code here

```
    class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.getName()+" the programmer";
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, I'm "+this.getTitle());
    }

    public void sayGoodbye() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye from "+getTitle());  
        /*
      Here i'm unable to call Person class getTitle(). while in php i can easily achieve this by using self::getTitle().
    */
    }
}

class Geek extends Person {
    Geek(String name) {
        super(name);  
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.getName()+" the geek";
    }
}

class This_Ex
{

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
Geek obj=new Geek("Avnish alok");
obj.sayHello();
obj.sayGoodbye();
}

}


/*This will output:

Hello, I'm Avnish alok the geek
Goodbye from Avnish alok the geek
*/
```

Look at my Person class sayGoodbye() method

```
System.out.println("Goodbye from "+getTitle());
```

here i want to use the method getTitle() of Person class only.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can call it using `super.getTitle()` in your Geek class getTitle() method. The same way you did for constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know you cannot do that. If you want to call a method specifically defined in Person you should declare it private and call it in Person. That way it can't be overridden. If you want it to be callable from outside of Person, but not overridable, you can declare it final. Either way, you'll want a separate method.

Cheers,
Marcus

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to **self** in Java. If a method is overridden in a subclass and the method is called using a subclass instance, the overridden method in the subclass is executed.

The subclasses have the option to invoke the superclass method using **super**, in your example, the subclass `getTitle()` method could be:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return super.getTitle() + " the geek";
}
```